# Generatorクラスを定義しているコードを、確認したいのですが

Tags: php

**[リンク先](http://blog.sarabande.jp/post/30716058960)に掲載されている下記コードについて**

> ジェネレータは Iterator インターフェイスを実装するクラスで次のメソッドが定義されています

```
final class Generator implements Iterator {
    void  rewind();
```

---

**[公式ドキュメント](http://php.net/manual/ja/class.generator.php)に書いている内容と同じですか？**
・公式ドキュメントにclassと記載がないのはなぜ？
・クラス概要だから、ソースコードそのものを掲載しているわけではない？？

---

**実際にソースコード上で確認するには？**
・[GitHUB](https://github.com/php/php-src/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Generator%20implements%20Iterator)上にあるのかと思い、検索したのですが、見つかりません
・ここではない？？
・あるいは、コンパイル前のC言語を検索しても見つからない？？

---

Comment: Iteratorを実装するクラス全般についての質問のようにタイトルからは受け取れますが、Generatorに関しての質問ということでよいのでしょうか？

Comment: Generatorに関する質問‌です。タイトル修正しました

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 公式ドキュメントにclassと記載がないのはなぜ？

タイトル等からクラスであることはわかりますし、単に省略しているだけでしょう。

そもそもPHPのメソッド定義に戻り値の型は書けませんから、マニュアルの表記はもちろん、ご指摘のサイトに書かれているのも疑似コードにすぎません。

> 実際にソースコード上で確認するには？

当該クラスがPHPコードで実装されているわけではないのはご想像の通りです。

ソースコード中で Generator クラスの定義を行っている個所は・・・多分ここですね。

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0/Zend/zend_generators.c#L1216-L1254

`ZEND_ME` マクロで定義された各メソッドの実体は、同じファイルに `ZEND_METHOD(Generator, ...)` で書かれています。

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.1.0/Zend/zend_generators.c#L876

ちなみに今回はキーワード「Generator」言語「C」で検索してこれを見つけましたが、ここでも使われている `INIT_CLASS_ENTRY` とクラス名で探すといいかもしれません。
<sub>といっても [SPL](http://php.net/manual/ja/book.spl.php) のクラスは `REGISTER_SPL_STD_CLASS_EX` なる独自のマクロが使われていましたが。。</sub>

Comment: 「マニュアルの表記はもちろん、ご指摘のサイトに書かれているのも疑似コードにすぎません」。なるほど、参考になりました